# Why I get screenshot blurry with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot

I'm trying to get a screenshot, but my result image is a little bit blurry. How can I fix it and make it more clear?

```
let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window!!
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 80), true, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
window.drawViewHierarchyInRect(window.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let windowImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 145))
windowImage.drawAtPoint(CGPoint(x: -0, y: -65))
let croppedImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(croppedImage, nil, nil, nil)
```

That's my code

Comment: @dasblinkenlight but I'm already setting my own resolution. No?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I even set scale to `0.0`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight no, I did not. But in the case of `0` it will equals to `0`. That's why on my question I took a screen.scale. Why you've asked it?

Answer (score 0):

Look at thats;

```
    UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 80)  UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 145))
windowImage.drawAtPoint(CGPoint(x: -0, y: -65))
```

Double check and change 80 and 145 and -0 , -65 i think different them in your main screen heights.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**You want to be using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()` for *both* of your image contexts**, and specifying the scale of the device's screen in both (or just input `0.0` to allow Core Graphics to auto-detect the screen scale).

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()` defaults to a scale of `1.0`, so you're effectively drawing a high resolution image in your first context, then downsampling it in your second.